Unable to Establish WebSocket Connection with Kubernetes Ingress and Socket.IO
I'm trying to establish a WebSocket connection between a client application and a Socket.IO server running in a Kubernetes cluster behind a Nginx Ingress controller. However, I'm unable to connect successfully.
Here's my current setup:
Ingress configuration:
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-websocket: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/websocket-services: "messaging-srv"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "3600"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "3600"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-http-version: "1.1"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connection-header: "upgrade"

spec:
  rules:
    - host: chat.dev
    http:
      paths:
        - path: /api/auth/?(.*)
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
              name: auth-srv
              port:
                number: 3000
      - path: /api/users/?(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: users-srv
            port:
              number: 3000
      - path: /api/messages/?(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: messaging-srv
            port:
              number: 3000                                   
      - path: /?(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: client-srv
            port:
              number: 3000

Messaging service code (index.ts):
import express from "express";
import { createServer } from "http";
import { Server } from "socket.io";

const app = express();
const server = createServer(app);
const io = new Server(server);

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log("Client connected!");
  socket.on("message", (data) => {
    console.log("Received message:", data);
  });

  // Handle socket disconnection
  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    console.log("Client disconnected!");
  });
});

app.get("/api/messages", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Get messages");
});

server.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Messaging Service listening on port 3000");
});

Testing and Configuration:
I'm using Postman for testing the WebSocket connection.

wss URL: wss://chat.dev/api/messages
Handshake URL: /socket.io (default)

The connection attempt doesn't seem to be successful. There are no errors in the logs of the messaging service.
Questions:

What could be causing the connection failure?
Are there any additional configuration steps required for the Ingress or messaging service?
Are there any known issues with using Postman for testing Socket.IO in Kubernetes environments?
Any insights or suggestions from the community would be greatly appreciated.

